# Iterator (iter()) function in Python.

Tags: python, iterator

For dictionary, I can use `iter()` for iterating over keys of the dictionary.

```
y = {"x":10, "y":20}
for val in iter(y):
    print val
```

When I have the iterator as follows,

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self, low, high):
        self.current = low
        self.high = high

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.current > self.high:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.current += 1
            return self.current - 1
```

Why can't I use it this way

```
x = Counter(3,8)
for i in x:
    print x
```

nor

```
x = Counter(3,8)
for i in iter(x):
    print x
```

but this way?

```
for c in Counter(3, 8):
    print c
```

What's the usage of `iter()` function?

#### ADDED

I guess this can be one of the ways of how `iter()` is used.

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self, low, high):
        self.current = low
        self.high = high

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.current > self.high:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.current += 1
            return self.current - 1

class Hello:
    def __iter__(self):
        return Counter(10,20)

x = iter(Hello())
for i in x:
    print i
```

Comment: Both your examples work for me. Python 2.6 here

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All of these work fine, except for a typo--you probably mean:

```
x = Counter(3,8)
for i in x:
    print i
```

rather than

```
x = Counter(3,8)
for i in x:
    print x
```

Comment: When iter(x) and x gives the same result, what's for the iter()? Thanks for finding the typo.

Comment: `iter` converts an object to an iterator (that is, it returns the iterator for an object).  When the object is *already* an iterator, this does nothing and `__iter__` simply returns itself.  `for i in x` is actually calling `iter` *for* you; since that's unnecessary (it's already an iterator), the iterator's `__iter__` call returns itself.

Answer (score 8):

I think your actual problem is that you `print x` when you mean to `print i`

`iter()` is used to obtain an iterator over a given object. If you have an `__iter__` method that defines what iter will actually do. In your case you can only iterate over the counter once. If you defined `__iter__` to return a new object it would make it so that you could iterate as many times as you wanted. In your case, Counter is already an iterator which is why it makes sense to return itself.