# How does iteration work in function

Tags: python, function, variables, for-loop, numpy

here's my problem. Sorry for the previous post which was not clear at all.

so here's an example:

```
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(1,100,1)
y=z=x*0

def func(h,g):
    for i in range(1,50):
        h[i]=i+1
        g[i]=i*2

func(z,y)
print z-y
```

In this example `z` and `y` give the same answer, but why is that so? In the function it is not supposed to give the same answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterator (iter()) function in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938927/iterator-iter-function-in-python)

Comment: @OP : You could also do this with `np.zeros(...)`.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Y I'm not confused about that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting `y` and `z` to both point to the same object.  This line:

```
y=z=x*0
```

creates one new object, x*0, then sets both y and z to refer to it.  Thus, `h` and `g` in your function are the same object, and the updates overwrite each other.

If you want to have two independent objects, create them independently:

```
y=x*0
z=x*0
```

Comment: Thank you! i thought the y=z=x*0 was just a way to reduce the number of lines!

Comment: Nope.  It literally sets y to the return value of `z=x*0`, which is `z`.